# ImageIO.write is saving image with distortion

Tags: java, image

Here is my painting method:

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
bi.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, rgbIntArray, 0, width);
ImageIO.write(bi, "bmp", new File("C:/Users/Felipe/Desktop/img2.bmp"));
```

This is how I populate the rgbIntArray:

```
rgbIntArray = new int[(rgbArray.length / 3)];
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < rgbArray.length; i += 3) 
{
    rgbIntArray[j] = unsignedToBytes(rgbArray[i]) + 
    unsignedToBytes(rgbArray[i + 1]) * 256 +
    unsignedToBytes(rgbArray[i + 2]) * 65536;
    j++;
}
```

I tested these values, they seem to be correct.

I think the problem is on the last parameter of `setRGB`, it asks for the "scanline stride", what to be honest I don`t have a clue what it is. (but I found somewhere it could be the width of the image). I'm assuming the other parameters are correct.

Here are the results:

> Original image:
>
> [Original image http://i.minus.com/jy7iVQxtghO0l.bmp](http://i.minus.com/jy7iVQxtghO0l.bmp)

---

> Result:
>
> [Result http://i.minus.com/jz86D3YkuPPhG.bmp](http://i.minus.com/jz86D3YkuPPhG.bmp)

I will manipulate the image after. I'm just opening and saving the same image.

Comment: How do you populate the rgbIntArray?

Comment: What is `rgbArray` in your block of code?

Comment: It is the B G R array read from the image.

Comment: I'm guessing `width` and/or `height` differ from those of the original image, most likely by 1 pixel. How do you initialize those two variables?

Comment: I just realized that width*height = 82075 and rgbIntArray.lenght = 82320 (there is 245 (width) more positions in the rgbIntArray)

Comment: Those multiplications by 256 and 65536 should really be left shifts by 8 and 16 respectively. Same effect but clearer.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you initialize `rgbArray`, but each row ends with a black pixel (outside the image). It might represent a new line if you initialized `rgbArray` by reading the bytes directly from the image file. Or you didn't initialize `rgbArray` correctly.

The black pixels show on the sheared image as a diagonal line.

You can skip the black pixels at the end of each row by changing this:

```
bi.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, rgbIntArray, 0, width);
```

to this:

```
bi.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, rgbIntArray, 0, width + 1);
```

The last parameter, `width + 1`, basically says that if a given row starts at a certain index in the array, then the next row will start at the index which is `width + 1` higher in the same array.